# SXA Add Query in the variant definition

Tags: sxa, sitecore-query

I am using SXA 1.7 and need to add a Query item under my variant definition, I found that the query should be written using sitecore query format like "query:./*" to return the child items but it doesn't return the data.

Also I need to know, how the child items field will be displayed, should I define the variant fields under the Query node in thevariant definition?

Comment: yes, define how items from the query will be rendered by adding variant fields under query item. The query works fine, make sure you define how they should be displayed.

Comment: Is the query field is available only for specific components as page content, for example if i am using search results, will it be available as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you define what will be displayed from items returned by Variant Query, it's quite simple:

[image]

If you are not sure if your query is working then make a quick test like in above example. Drop Page Content on the Home item, add some pages under the home and if you will put following query `query:./*` in the Query field of Variant Query it should return Home children:

[image]